# Drupal 8 : How to stop drupal stocking sessions?

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-8

I created a module to authenticate users thanks to a card and I need to check if they can access the website.

The problem is with the way Drupal manages sessions. It stocks every sessions in the database and restores it, so the user is automatically logged in, this causes the user to not go through the checking process.

Is it possible to stop stocking the sessions in the database ?

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8 you can set the cookie/session lifetimes in 
**/sites/default/services.yml**

Setting the cookie_lifetime to 0 would mean the user's session only lasts until the browser tab is closed, so when they revisit the site they'll need to log in again.

E.g. services.yml

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    # Default ini options for sessions.
    #
    # Some distributions of Linux (most notably Debian) ship their PHP
    # installations with garbage collection (gc) disabled. Since Drupal depends
    # on PHP's garbage collection for clearing sessions, ensure that garbage
    # collection occurs by using the most common settings.
    # @default 1
    gc_probability: 1
    # @default 100
    gc_divisor: 100
    #
    # Set session lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the user's last
    # visit to the active session may be deleted by the session garbage
    # collector. When a session is deleted, authenticated users are logged out,
    # and the contents of the user's $_SESSION variable is discarded.
    # @default 200000
    gc_maxlifetime: 200000
    #
    # Set session cookie lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the session
    # is created to the cookie expires, i.e. when the browser is expected to
    # discard the cookie. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed".
    # @default 2000000
    cookie_lifetime: 0
```